# Is it possible to set multi-column index order?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a column multi-index, which I get from an unstack operation since I want to plot multiple boxplots at once.

The second level of that multi-index is a categorical (r), with its order defined and different from alphabetical order.
When I do

```
dh2.sort_index(axis=1,level=['P','r'],inplace=True)
```

on the unstacked DataFrame to select the order of box plot x-axis, the `r` values are sorted alphabetically, and therefore in the wrong order!

How can I get the correct order?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we don't have to make up data to show you.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that the order of categories you want is `['a','c','b']`:

```py
import pandas as pd
t = pd.DataFrame(data={'P':[0,1,2], 
                       'r':['a','c','b'],
                       'x':[1.,2.,3.]})
t['r'] = t['r'].astype('category', ordered=True, categories=['a','c','b'])
t.set_index(['P','r'], inplace=True)
t.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

```
     x
P r     
a 0  1.0
c 1  2.0
b 2  3.0
```

Comment: Yes. So far so good.  But now I want to do a multiple Boxplot  of column `param` for all values of P and r. Therefore, I do `t['param'].unstack(level=['P','r'])`. After this, pandas doesn't know anymore that r (now a column multi-index) is a categorical. And when the `sort_index` command is executed, `r` is sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Could you do sorting of the index *after* you do `unstack`?

Comment: S.V., I *do* a sorting of the columns after unstack. This is because I want to plot the various `r` groups together for each `P` value. That's the statement at the top. But that sorting does not understand that `r` is (was?) a categorical and sorts alphabetically instead. Hence my plot is incorrect.